# Convert cells inside a cell array to cell arrays - matlab

Tags: matlab, cell-array

*Do not get confused with row numbers in the arrays. I am just asking converting 1 into style 2*

This is Cell Array C

[image: cell array 1]

I want to convert it to the below version how can i do that ?

V2 =

[image: cell array 1 converted to v2]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a flat cell array of strings (which contain valid MATLAB cell array definitions), and you want to convert each string into a sub-cell-array of its own. So what you need is:

```
cellfun(@eval, C, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Where `C` is the original cell array of strings.

**Example:**

```
C = {'{''samsung'', ''n150'', ''jp0xtr'', ''n570''};'; ...
    '{''samsung'', ''n150'', ''jp0xtr'', ''beyaz''};'}
C2 = cellfun(@eval, C, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

The result is:

```
C = 

    '{'samsung', 'n150', 'jp0xtr', 'n570'};'
    '{'samsung', 'n150', 'jp0xtr', 'beyaz'};'


C2 = 

    {1x4 cell}
    {1x4 cell}
```